# Charge operator for Dirac spinor

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, charge, fermions, antimatter, dirac-equation

In QED, the gauge transformation which acts upon a fermionic field $\psi$ is 
$$\psi'(x)= e^{i \alpha(x) Q}\psi(x)$$
where $Q$ is the charge operator. Most of the time it's just written as
$$\psi'(x)= e^{-i \alpha(x)}\psi(x)$$
However, if the general solution of the Dirac equation is
$$\psi(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
  u(x)  \\
  v(x)  
 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $u$ is the vector with electron fields and $v$ with positron fields, then how can the second formula be true, if $Q u = + u$ and $Q v = -v$? In that case we would get
$$Q \psi(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
  u(x)  \\
  -v(x)  
 \end{pmatrix}\neq -\psi$$

Comment: what if either $u=0$ or $v=0$?

Comment: I don't believe that's the case when you have the most general QED lagrangian

Comment: Can you give some reference? I have never seen a charge operator in the exponential...

Comment: Halzen & Martin, "Quarks and leptons", formula (15.2)

Answer (score 2):

The point is that a Dirac field isn't really a solution for an electron and positron but instead an electron and the conjugate of the positron. This means that the Dirac electron field does indeed obey,
\begin{equation} 
e ^{ i \alpha (x) Q } \psi = e ^{ - i \alpha (x) } \psi 
\end{equation}

Such misconceptions are dissolved if one works in the Weyl representation. There the fundamental (2-component) fields which make the Lagrangian are, $ e _L , e _R ^c  $ (where $ e _L $ is negatively charged and $ e _R ^c $ is positive). Then a Dirac fermion is,
\begin{equation} 
\psi = \left( \begin{array}{c} 
e _L  \\  
( e _R ^c ) ^\dagger  
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}